# Proof that exist $y \in \mathbb R$ for which $f(y)=f(y+2019)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Proof that exist $y \in \mathbb R$ for which $f(y)=f(y+2019)$ if you know that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous, $f(19)=0,01$ and $f(x)<0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x|\ge100$.

Thanks for knowledge witch I have in this task I know that this function have the highest value because if this function is continuos and $f(x)<0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x|\ge100$ so $f(x)>0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x|<100$ from the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem in interval $[-100,100]$ I have the highest value.
 Unfortunately I don't know what to do to go $f(y)=f(y+2019)$.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand this at all. Please try to re-word it to be more clear.

Comment: What does 0,01 mean?

Comment: @copper.hat: It is the standard notation for $0.01$ in [about half the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Arabic_numerals).

Comment: No wonder there are so many problems in the world.

Comment: @copper.hat: what, because they don't use the same decimal separator as you?

Comment: @TonyK: I only use whole numbers. Lighten up.

Comment: @copper.hat: and Roman numerals, right?

Comment: Yes, $0,01$ means $0.01$. I know that in promming it is used $0.01$ but I didn't know that in some countries people don't know what is $0,01$ so I'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You're searching for a zero of the function $g(y) := f(y + 2019) - f(y)$.  What properties of this function $g$ can you deduce?  In particular, what can you say about $g(19)$, and what can you say about $g(-2000)$?

Comment: @Daniel Schepler $g(19)=f(2038)-f(19)$ and $g(-2000)=f(19)-f(-2000)$ so I have $g(19)+g(-2000)=f(2038)-f(-2000)>0$ but I don't know what can I do with it

Comment: @MP3129 OK, let's focus on $g(19)$: you know the value of $f(19)$, right?  What can you say about $f(2038)$?

Comment: @Daniel Schepler $f(2038)<0$, $-f(19)=-0.01$ so $g(19)<0$

Comment: Unfortunately Istill do not know how to do it. @TonyK maybe you have some tips?

Comment: By a similar argument, you should be able to show $g(-2000) > 0$.  So now, you know $g(-2000) > 0$ and $g(19) < 0$, and you want to show there is some $y$ such that $g(y) = 0$...

Comment: OK, I see your point now. +1.